# How can I manage bookmarks in Android Firefox?

Tags: sync, firefox-for-android

I have tried following the directions given here:-

http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/828180

However, I am not seeing a Mobile Bookmarks folder on my PC's bookmarks section within Firefox 16.0.1 so do nto know how to get this working in two-way sync between devices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what i did. Assuming you've set up the sync process:

1. Go to Firefox on your PC, click `Bookmarks` in the top right corner
2. Choose `Unsorted Bookmarks`. This opened a new window for me where i could see a section called `Mobile bookmarks` that i hadn't seen anywhere else.
3. Click and drag this `Mobile Bookmarks` folder to either `Bookmarks Toolbar` or `Bookmarks Menu`, whichever you want it to appear under (Note: the `Bookmarks Menu` is what we clicked on to start this process, i advise you try both and see which you like best).
4. Profit.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Strangely the Mobile Bookmarks folder appeared where it had not previously been so all seems fine.

Comment: glad to hear it worked out!